# How to use iterator loop in Jinja2/Django templates?

Tags: python, django, templates, jinja2

I want to print the index of the list 'seq1': seq1[0], seq1[1], etc. But in Jinja2, I cannot use the index of a list to find positions.

But as I would like to put this in a loop, I need to manipulate the indices.

**I would like code similar to this:**

```
{% for item in seq1 %}
    {{seq1.item}}

{% endfor %}
```

It gives:

```
{{seq.1}}
```

Can someone help me? I need to use HTML tags to color this list.

Comment: you don't need the index, you can loop through the items themselves: `{% for item in seq %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}`. Inside the for loop, you can access the current index with `{{ loop.index }}` (in jinja) or `{{ forloop.counter }}` in django. Also there's the `{{ loop.cycle }}` construct that lets you cycle between various values, e.g. to change the colour of a list item.

Comment: Also you say in your title you get an error. But you're not showing us the error nor are you showing us the code that produces the error.

Comment: Possibly not relevant, but are you sure you are using Jinja2 rather than Django templates?